# Add expressions to LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace

Tags: latex, auctex, electric-pair-mode

I would want to "electrically" insert `|` or `\right|` when typing `|` or `\left|` in AucTeX and can't quite figure out how to add characters to AucTex-electric. A list of already defined completions can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/s/auctex/manual/auctex/Quotes.html). Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the following lisp snippet into your init-file:

```el
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace t)
        (local-set-key "|" 'LaTeX-insert-left-brace)))
```

Maybe, `(setq LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace t)` is not really necessary since you have it already customized or hooked in. Nevertheless, it does not hurt if you keep it.

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you very much!