# AUCTeX pairing large parenthesis for `\left(`

Tags: auctex, balanced-parentheses

I'd like to automatically close `\left(` with `\right)` in LaTeX via AUCTeX in Emacs 27. The following should work:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
            (lambda () (set (make-local-variable 'TeX-electric-math)
                            (cons "\\left(" "\\right)"))))
```

But it doesn't. Any clues as to why it doesn't and how I could make it work?

PS: the solution [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48359/add-expressions-to-latex-electric-left-right-brace)
adds an extra parenthesis, so in the end you have `\left(\right))`.

Comment: Have you seen the description for `LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace` in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-LaTeX_002delectric_002dleft_002dright_002dbrace)?

Comment: Blimey! Sorry for the bother! I had forgotten about `LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace`! The funny thing is, I have it in my `init`, but I had commented it out, can't remember why. Thank you!